# How to run gacultil in window command prompt?

Tags: .net

I want to deploy .net assemblies to the end users' PC (win7 or xp, with .net framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, ...). The .net assemblies need to add to GAC & Register.
Is it possible to run visual studio command promt without installing visual studio?

PS:
To use .Net non-visual assemblies in PowerBuilder Classic Win32 targets using COM Callable Wrappers (CCWs), Need to set up before using:
1. Add to GAC,  run gacultil.exe in Visual Studio command prompt ;
2. Register,  run regasm.exe in window command prompt;

Have any suggestion ?

Thanks !

Jack

Comment: [GacUtil is a development app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205188/whats-the-correct-way-of-registering-installing-an-assembly-to-the-gac), use an installer to properly register assemblies.

Comment: I think it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950628/c-sharp-how-to-register-assembly-in-the-gac-without-gacutil

Comment: Images not found in  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58021-deploying-a-c%23-application-visual-studio-setup-project/