# registering a dll in GAC

Tags: c#, assemblies, gac

I need to add an dll to GAC on Windows 2003 server.
The server doesn't have Visual Studio installed.
I didnt find Gacutil.exe in Windows 2003 Server.
Where can I find Gacutil in Windows 2003 Server.
Is there any other way I can add a dll to GAC .
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: It is a Windows SDK tool, not available with .NET.  It is the job of a setup program to put assemblies in the GAC, quite easy to do with a Setup and Deployment project.  Writing your own gacutil is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611108/register-a-dll-into-the-gac-but-then-it-doesnt-show-up-in-the-assembly-window/2611435#2611435

Comment: You don't have to have VS installed. Only the .net framework is enough.

Comment: There is an old gacutil.exe in .net framework 1.1 that is dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't (re: shouldn't) use GACUtil.exe, there are 2 other ways, outlined in the following link from msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx

What you're looking for is probably `Mscorcfg.msc`, but is only good for Framework version 3.5 and earlier

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call gacutil. There are some fusion APIs you can P/Invoke.

Instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317540

Comment: Is there any other way where we can add a dll to GAC.

Comment: MSI installer can do it for you.