# Viewer tool for Global Assembly Cache (Viewer)

Tags: .net, gac, gacutil, clr4.0

To view a list of the assemblies in the global assembly cache, at the command prompt, type the following command: gacutil –l

In earlier versions of the .NET Framework, the Shfusion.dll Windows shell extension enabled you to view the global assembly cache in Windows Explorer. Beginning with the .NET Framework version 4, Shfusion.dll is obsolete.

Any visual tool view the contents of the global assembly cache in .NET 4.0 - CLR 4.0 ? I would like viewer tool and not execute commandline (gacutil -l).

UPDATE:

GACView by Nirsoft.net does not support .NET 4.0 (CLR 4.0)

http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/gac_viewer.html

Update march 2012:

GAC Browser
http://gacbrowser.blogspot.com/2008/03/gac-browser-introduction.html

Comment: This is a shopping question, off topic at SE sites.  Make it a programming question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611108/register-a-dll-into-the-gac-but-then-it-doesnt-show-up-in-the-assembly-window/2611435#2611435

Comment: Can I move another site in SE ? which better forum for questions about tools in C# .NET ?

Comment: @Hans Passant: I disagree, I am a developer and searcht for the OP's topic right here at SO, expecting to get help. This question belongs to SO IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GAC Browser is useful for GAC CLR 2.0 and CLR 4.0
http://gacbrowser.blogspot.com/2008/03/gac-browser-introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GACView](http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/gac_viewer.html) by Nirsoft?

Comment: GACView not supports .NET 4.0 - CLR 4.0

Comment: @Kiquenet if you point GACView to the folder architecture specific folder (e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32) it does show the assemblies although it does not display all the information. Not a perfect solution for sure, but it is something :).