# assembly loading just after installing it in GAC

Tags: c#, assemblies

I have an program which calls a msi installer. After the msi package is  installed successfully I tried to load a assembly which was added by the msi package in the GAC. I am not able to load the assembly but this particular assembly is being added to the GAC. When i run the program for the second time the assembly gets loaded properly. 
here is the pseudocode

```
load assembly(assemblyname)
{
 if(!Assembly.load(assemblyname))
 msi.install();
 Assembly assembly =Assembly.load(assemblyname)
 if(assembly == null)
  console.writeline("assembly not loaded"); 
}
```

If the msi package is not installed already , i always get assembly not loaded for the first time when I run this function.
Somehow I think this is related to the GAC list which is present before the program gets executed. Is there a way where I can reload this?

Comment: I reckon it's caching the result

Comment: you could try doing the first test in a different appdomain

Comment: Have you tried using the fully qualified assembly name?

Comment: How does msi.install know when it's done?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i wait till the  msi installation is done.

Comment: @terrybozzio I will try that and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo code as posted will certainly fail.  The CLR remembers previous Assembly.Load() failures and will fail them consistently afterwards, even if the assembly became available.

It isn't clear why you attempt to load the assembly again.  Get ahead by either assuming it is properly installed if the install didn't fail or just always install and leave it up to the installer to detect that the assembly is already present.  If that's not practical then you need to use the [IAssemblyCache interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611435/17034) to check for presence, QueryAssemblyInfo() method.