# GAC Files from C# Code

Tags: c#, installation, clickonce, gac

I am trying to add new DLLs to the GAC (Global Assembly Cache) from C# code. Is this even possible? what is the best way to do it?

We are using a clickonce installer to update an application. I want to be able to GAC from the code any new DLLs that are new in the solution.

These files need to be in the GAC, as a requirement.

Comment: may be you can try **gacutil.exe** in a batch file and run the batch file from the c# code.

Comment: By my understanding gacutil only comes with VS, the end user dont necessarily have Visual Studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2611435/17034

Comment: Do you want clickonce to add assemblies to the GAC? Or do you want your C# code to add other assemblies to the GAC, like gacutil?

Comment: I will like to add it via C# code, gacutil is not an option because  is not available on all computers. the only problem with using Clickonce to GAC the Dlls is that i need to have several versions of the same DLL i don't think clickone manage that out of the box

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from C# using the GAC/Fusion API documented [here](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/317540?wa=wsignin1.0) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404523.aspx). An example in C# can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611108/register-a-dll-into-the-gac-but-then-it-doesnt-show-up-in-the-assembly-window/2611435#2611435) (thanks to Hans Passant), [here](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#PowerShellGac/PowerShellGac/GlobalAssemblyCache.cs) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/09/14/229649.aspx). A simpler alternative are the GacInstall and GacRemove methods of the [System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.internal.publish.aspx) class, but they lack features and proper error reporting.