# Way to create a little gacutil.exe installation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, gacutil

I would like to create or download a little installation package for the GacUtil.exe.

I know that gacutil is a part of the .Net SDK, but i would like to be able to create a redistributable install of the gacutil.exe.

Anyone already do this ? I need to know the dependencies of this exe.

Anyone have some informations about this ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Comment: Sounds fishy. I supect this is a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask the original question instead. Btw did you check the license that you can redistribute GacUtil.exe ?

Comment: What is your end goal exactly?

Comment: Simply, i create a DLL for Navision. When i installed the DLL, i need to copy on the assembly cache. When i want to install my dll, some servers don't have the gacutil.exe.

Comment: That's why you use an installer. GacUtil is not a redistributable.

Comment: Msdn says you [shouldn't use gacutil.exe to production pupose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is only for dev.

Comment: So the only way is to create an Installer with Visual Studio ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2611435/17034