# Unregister assemblies from GAC using wildcards

Tags: .net, windows, gac, fusion, gacutil

I have a large number of assemblies to un-register from the GAC, I'd rather not have to go through them one at a time.

Is it possible to use wildcards in the `gacutil`?

*(or, a batch\Powershell script)*

Comment: You are a programmer, write the code.  You'll [need this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2611435/17034).

Comment: Why dont you use MSI? You can let MSI do the gac installation part.

Comment: I know I could do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of an opensource and free to use PowerShell module called [PowerShell GAC](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com/) which can unregister a large number of assemblies from the GAC. You could use the following command if you run it as administrator.

```
Get-GacAssembly -Name SomeAssembly* | Remove-GacAssembly
```

Filtering on assembly version is also possible using the -Version parameter