# Install into the global assembly cache (GAC) programmatically with c#

Tags: c#, dll, gac

Can a DLL be installed into the global assembly cache programmatically with c#?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611108/register-a-dll-into-the-gac-but-then-it-doesnt-show-up-in-the-assembly-window/2611435#2611435

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.